# Indexes for random queries across 1.5M lines table

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, sum

I have a pretty big mysql table of 1.5 Millions lines.
There are 7 columns identifying the Data with labels (varchar), and 38 Columns containing Numeric (Decimal) Data;

The data are organized that way

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ... | Data1 | Data2 | Data3
A1   |  B1  |  C1  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A1   |  B1  |  C2  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A1   |  B1  |  C3  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A1   |  B2  |  C1  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A1   |  B2  |  C2  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A1   |  B2  |  C3  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A2   |  B1  |  C1  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A2   |  B1  |  C2  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A2   |  B1  |  C3  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A2   |  B2  |  C1  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A2   |  B2  |  C2  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789  
A2   |  B2  |  C3  | ... |  123  |  456  | 789
```

Now, I'm running queries like:

```
select ColA, ColB, Sum(DATA1), Sum(DATA2), group by ColA, ColB
```

But my queries can be composed of any columns in any order, like

```
select ColC, ColA Sum(DATA5), Sum(DATA2), group by ColA, ColC
```

and this is not predictable, however, All queries will be composed of at least 1 Label column, and one data column. All data column will be summed, and label column grouped.

I can't create a single index on all columns as the size would be above maximum. 
I could create all possible indexes combinations between all columns, but i'm not sure it will be better and it will require thousands of indexes.

What I have in mind is to create indexes between all data columns and the Label columns, like:

```
key (ColA, ColB, ColC, ..., Data1)
key (ColB, ColA, ColC, ..., Data1)
key (ColB, ColC, ColA, ..., Data1)
...
```

Would that be a valid solution ?
Any other (better) idea ?

Comment: [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: Indexes really only affect you `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses. If you are selecting all rows from the table, it won't matter what indexes you have. Can you provide any details on the limits you are appling to the query (either through joins or where conditions).

Comment: Hello Declan, I don't use any join. my table contains mostly statistical data that are organized like this: Country > Building type > Energy efficiency > ...   The goal is to provide reports to users. They might want to have the total numbers of building of type A per country, which means, mysql will need to make a sum on hundres of thousands lines. My goal is to find a way to pre calculate the result of SUM to speed up those queries, and I though indexes would do that, but maybe I misreaded.

Comment: I would agree with @eggyal that a different model of data is well worth considering. Failing that I would just resort to putting an index on each of your 7 label columns. Not perfect but it will likely provide a useful index for most of your queries.

Comment: The issue is that my queries are generated based on the data the user want to display, a bit like excel pivot table, so all combination of SELECT and Group BY can be possible, and I don't really see how I can make another model in that situation. Since I need to sum data for every possible way, using aggregate tables would gives me 7! = 5040 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I might have found a solution. It turns out that the order of the columns doesn't change the result, for example: select ColA, ColB, Sum(data1) group by ColA, ColB will return the same data as: select ColB, ColA, Sum(data1) group by ColB, ColA It might be therefore possible to make an algorithm that will consolidate all data into: 7(7-1)/2 + 6(6-1)/2 + 5(5-1)2 = 56 tables (if I'm right). Alternately, I can get a better server and have innodb pool size big enough (let's say 2Go) to have all the mysql table in ram. –